# How to rename JSON element in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have an API that response JSON data like this-

```
  {
"unitcode":"apple",
"description":"bus",
"color":"red",
"intent":"Name 1"
 }
```

I want to change like this-

```
  {
"Value1":"apple",
"Value2":"bus",
"value3":"red",
"value4":"sale"
 }
```

Presently, I can code to rename single key but i want some code to replace all key in one shot. my code like this-

```
request(baseurl)
        .then( body => {
             var unit = JSON.parse(body);
             unit.intent = "sales"
             unit.value1 = unit.unitcode
             delete unit.unitcode;
             console.log(unit)
             console.log(unit.Value1)
             var unit2 = JSON.stringify(unit)

        // let code = unit.description;
         conv.ask('Sales is 1 million metric tonnes ' + unit2);
          })
```

please help me out on this and please little elaborate also to learn something new. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a Map of original key to new key (`transformMap`). Convert the object to pairs of [key, value] with `Object.entries()`, iterate with `Array.map()` and replace the replacement key from the Map (or the original if not found). Convert back to an object with `Object.toEntries()`:

```js
const transformMap = new Map([
  ['unitcode', 'Value1'],
  ['description', 'Value2'],
  ['color', 'Value3'],
  ['intent', 'Value4']
]);

const transformKeys = obj =>
  Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj)
    .map(([k, v]) => [transformMap.get(k) || k, v])
  );

const obj = {
  "unitcode": "apple",
  "description": "bus",
  "color": "red",
  "intent": "Name 1"
};

const result = transformKeys(obj)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know the object structure and it is constant, you could just use destructing like so.

```js
const data =  {
"unitcode":"apple",
"description":"bus",
"color":"red",
"intent":"Name 1"
 };
 
 // If the object is fixed and the fields are known. 
 const mapData = ({ unitcode, description, color, intent }) => ({
  Value1: unitcode,
  Value2: description,
  Value3: color,
  Value4: intent
 });
 
 console.log(JSON.stringify(mapData(data)));
```

But if the object has an unknown number of properties:

```js
const data =  {
"unitcode":"apple",
"description":"bus",
"color":"red",
"intent":"Name 1"
 };
 
 // If the object is fixed and the fields are known. 
 const mapData = (data) => {
  return Object.keys(data).reduce((a,v,i) => {
    a[`Value${i+1}`] = data[v];
    return a;
   }, {});
 };
 
 console.log(JSON.stringify(mapData(data)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Well your target is to modify the keys and retain the value
In that context, you can iterate through your data. To dynamically generate keys as `Value1`, `Value2`, etc, we will append `Value` with iteration index which is going to be unique always.

```
const modifyInput = (input) => {
    const modifiedInput = {}
    Object.values(input).forEach((item, index) => {
        modifiedInput[`Value${index + 1}`] = item
    })
    return modifiedInput
}
```

Use this function, pass your input and get your desired result

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to OP's problem, it is highly recommended that you provide additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question. Code only answers typically become useless in the long-run because future viewers experiencing similar problems cannot understand the reasoning behind the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the array to have the values you need

```
    let i=0,j=0,unit1={};
    let unit = JSON.parse(body);
    let unit3=["val1","val2","val3","val4"]
    let unit5=Object.values(unit);
    for(let key in unit){
        unit1[unit3[i++]]=unit5[j++];
    }
    var unit2 = JSON.stringify(unit1)

console.log('Sales is 1 million metric tonnes \n' + unit2);
//Sales is 1 million metric tonnes 
//{"val1":"apple","val2":"bus","val3":"red","val4":"Name 1"}
```